# launching silverlight app on Mac OS

Tags: silverlight, macos

Is there a way to launch out of browser Silverlight app on Mac OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/mtaulty/Silverlight-3-Running-Out-Of-Browser-Apps-on-the-Macintosh) on how to achieve this.

Comment: Please provide some detail in the answer. As soon as that video 404's, and it will eventually, this answer will be junked